# Как сделать кнопку переноса статьи в другой раздел сайта django

Tags: django

Суть в чем, мне требуется на сайте в статьях сделать кнопку "в архив"
Сами стать находится в работе и по завершению работы что бы клиент нажал "выполнено" Он переносил его в раздел архив
Подскажите как это реализовать, если есть статьи на этот повод то буду признателен.
Уже третий день ищу как это можно сделать.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Ну, как я понял вам надо, чтобы статьи можно было кидать в некий архив? Допустим в вашей модели есть поле is_archive, которое либо True, либо False. Сделать форму и соответственно кнопку при нажатии которой is_archive присваивается значение True и потом в шаблоне делать проверку, если у вашей статьи значение is_archive является False, то отображать ее, а если True, то не отображать. А в архиве сделать наоборот, если у статьи is_archive=True, то отображать ее. Наверное так.

Comment: При новом заказе он появляется у меня на главной Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку заказ завершён он у меня появлялся в категории архив на сайте

Comment: Возьмём пример категории форумов если создаётся например сообщение в неправильном категории то администратор может его переместить вот как мне реализовать такое же только с помощью кнопки